# substring from specific point of the string(from reverse side )

Tags: c#

I wanted to substring from special point.

> abcdef.png

I want

> .png

Here i tried

```
    string str = "abcdef.png";
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 4);
```

but then only shows the abcdef only BUT i want .png part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method instead of substring.

```
string str = "abcdef.png";
string ext = Path.GetExtension(str); // .png
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use the [overload which takes a single parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - the start point:

```
str = str.Substring(str.Length - 4);
```

Or better, use a method *designed* to get the extension of a filename - [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're dealing with file names, Use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `str.Length - 4` as the first (and only) parameter, not as the second parameter:

```
str = str.Substring(str.Length - 4);
```

The way your code had it, you got a substring starting at zero, and containing `str.Length - 4` characters.

If you want to take just the dot and the extension, use

```
str = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the extension of a filename use `Path.GetExtension(str)`. Much easier.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try below code it will return the extension of file.

string extension = Path.GetExtension(str);